# How to extract company address from website

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I have been browsing, trying and reading different codes from here but i can't get mine to work. What i am trying to do:

1. Browse a web which contains all information about the country's companies.
2. Look up the company in the website (taking as reference the name from a excel cell).
3. When the company web loads, extract "Domicilio" (address) from it and past it on another excel cell.

Information to take into account:

1. Website is: https://www.infocif.es/
2. Form to look up is: https://www.infocif.es/general/empresas-informacion-listado-empresas.asp?Buscar= , so if you want to search "014 media SL" company, it would be https://www.infocif.es/general/empresas-informacion-listado-empresas.asp?Buscar=014 media SL
3. If you load the previous link, which leads to the final link https://www.infocif.es/ficha-empresa/014-media-sl, you will see in the "informacion de la compañia" div, the needed "domicilio" information. In this case, i would like to extract: Calle Alcala 106 Primero  28009  - Madrid

what i have tried so far. The following codes from some great people on this web:

clsHTTP (MODULE CLASS)

```
Option Explicit

Private http As Object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetHTML(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
        With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        GetHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetDomicilio(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As String
    On Error GoTo errhand:
     GetDomicilio = html.querySelector("div.row p:nth-child(6)").innerText
    Exit Function
errhand:
    GetDomicilio = "Not Found"
End Function
```

Standard module

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim http As clsHTTP, sResponse As String, lastRow As Long, groupResults(), i As Long, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://www.infocif.es/general/empresas-informacion-listado-empresas.asp?Buscar="
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case lastRow
        Case 1
            Exit Sub
        Case 2
            ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = .Range("A2").Value
        Case Else
            arr = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
        End Select

        ReDim groupResults(1 To lastRow - 1)

        With http
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                If Len(BASE_URL & arr(i, 1)) > Len(BASE_URL) Then
                    sResponse = .GetHTML(BASE_URL & arr(i, 1))
                    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
                    groupResults(i) = .GetDomicilio(html)
                    sResponse = vbNullString: html.body.innerHTML = vbNullString
                End If
            Next
        End With
        For i = LBound(groupResults) To UBound(groupResults)
            .Cells(i + 1, "B") = groupResults(i)
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have been trying to figure it out, and i believe that it is failing by 2 reasons:

1. the Base URL is wrong, or
2. I cant properly define the queryselector for "domicilio".

What am i getting when i run the code above?

It will run, no issues, but it will return a "not found" reply on b column.  Please, assume that all  the company names are listed on A column (there are like 1800 rows). Company names start by A2.

You can try the following companies:

```
014 MEDIA SL
100M MONTADITOS INTERNACIONAL SL
649298 CASTELLON SL
ABACO ASESORES PERICIALES SL
ABADA SA
ABELLCON 3 SL
ABEX-EXCELENCIA ROBOTICA SL
ABF IBERIA HOLDING SL
ABRAFACT SL
ACCENTURE HOLDINGS IBERIA SL
ACCESORIOS DE TUBERIA SA
ACCESORIOS FRIGORIFICOS SA
ACCIONA MOBILITY SA
```

Comment: did you try your url in web browser? You put wrong arguments. You set `01420%25media20%25SL` but it has to use `%20` (or `+`) instead of `20%25` - like `014%20media%20SL` or `014+media+SL`. But in browser works also directly `014 media SL` (with spaces)

Comment: Hello. i don't have a problem to load the company page. The issue is i am not getting any  result when extracting the address. I dont even believe that it is recording it in GetDomicilio. Looks like nth-child is not supported and i got to use something else...

Comment: I would first display HTML to see if you get expected elements. Eventually you can try to get all `p` and later get 6th item in VBA. But I don't use Windows/Excel to test it.

Comment: I have replaced the queryselector for "GetDomicilio" to getelementsbytag. Previous code was GetDomicilio = html.querySelector("div.row p:nth-child(6)").innerText and new code is GetDomicilio = html.getElementsByClassName("editable col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 mb10 text-right")(2).innerText . It does work now, but will only retrieve 12/1800, and then will just fail to add the following ones (not found). Anyways. it takes a long while just to get these 12 ones. Any idea how to get all of the 1800 and speed it a little bit up?

Comment: maybe first check simpler ie.`html.getElementsByClassName(editable)` to see if you get anything. Next try with longer name, etc. But for some tools `"editable col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 mb10 text-right"` is not single class name but many names. BTW: if page uses JavaScript to add element then sometimes it needs time to add them and code may need to sleep short time .

Comment: something shorter as "editable" throws the same result. 12/1800 and takes about the same time. what i need to get now is the right selector...

Comment: first you could check what you have in `sResponse` - maybe you get different HTML then in web browser.

Comment: when I run `querySelector("div.row p:nth-child(6)")` in browser then I get list with 4 results and I need `[0]` to get first element and extract text - `querySelector("div.row p:nth-child(6)")[0].innerText`

Comment: Nth seems to be not supported on vba. maybe something like first-child or that sort could work..

Comment: maybe you should get all elements and later in VBA get N-th element

Comment: LOL!! How didnt i notice it before. It stops by 12/1800 because the website requires you to login/register after 11/12 tries.

Comment: And i cant use that website. it asks to for an "im not a robot" checkbox...

Comment: there are paid portals to resolve Captcha - ie. https://2captcha.com/ - maybe it would help. But it may need to write code in language supported by this page